# Access to USB Ethernet adapter in LXC

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, lxc

I've created a LXC container in Ubuntu 18.04. Physically, there is an USB to Ethernet adapter connected on the host machine. After starting the LXC container, how to access the USB ethernet adapter? Are there configurations for LXC to do?

The info on the Host machine:

```
rui@rui-desktop:~$ ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::f763:92fe:8145:163  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0e:c6:c9:1a:18  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1  bytes 46 (46.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 158  bytes 29470 (29.4 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1430
    inet 173.39.202.159  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast 173.39.202.255
    inet6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:12c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:e0:4c:68:01:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1911906  bytes 851840909 (851.8 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 350546  bytes 25613552 (25.6 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 149  base 0xd000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 35420  bytes 2918763 (2.9 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 35420  bytes 2918763 (2.9 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lxcbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.3.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe00:0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:16:3e:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 859  bytes 86124 (86.1 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 831  bytes 88890 (88.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

rndis0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether be:86:e5:ee:9a:ed  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether be:86:e5:ee:9a:ef  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

eth0 is the interface that I want to access, and the output from lsusb is

```
rui@rui-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
**Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0b95:7720 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772**
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

LXC container info:

```
Last login: Sat Feb 24 17:40:28 UTC 2018 on pts/0
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.9.140-tegra aarch64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

cisco@ul:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
40: eth0@if41: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:16:3e:d6:9b:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
inet 10.0.3.194/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 3586sec preferred_lft 3586sec
inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fed6:9b38/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding these setting in /var/lib/lxc/ul/config make it working.

`lxc.net.1.type = phys
 lxc.net.1.link = eth0
 lxc.net.1.flags = up
 lxc.net.1.hwaddr = 00:0e:c6:c9:1a:18`